# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DateField' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

In my model there are `start_date_time`, `end_date_time`, `period` and `period_type` fields, where `end_date_time` must be equal to sum of `start_date_time` and timedelta. And in my case timedelta's day is equal to `period` and `period_type` is one of days/months/years/. Here are my codes:

`models.py`:

```
class PeriodTypeEnum(models.IntegerChoices):
    Years = 'years'
    Months = 'months'
    Days = 'days'

class Policy(models.Model):
    policy_type = models.ForeignKey('PolicyType', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blank = models.OneToOneField('blank_app.Blank', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    period = models.IntegerField()
    period_type = models.IntegerField(choices=PeriodTypeEnum.choices)
    start_date_time = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date_time = models.DateField(default = start_date_time + timedelta(days=1), blank=True, null=True)
```

P.S: in `end_date_time` field, timedelta(days + x) - x must be equal to `period`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't support dependencies like that in `default`.

The easiest thing to do here is to declare

```
end_date_time = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and add a

```
def clean(self):
    if not self.end_date_time:
         # (or do something with `self.period`?)
         self.end_date_time = self.start_date_time + timedelta(days=1)
```

to the model. Remember that `.clean()` is only called by forms and such, not when you `.save()`, so if you want that, you'll need to override `.save()` too.

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    self.clean()
    return super().save(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you buddy, but this method is not working. It returns `super() argument 1 must be type, not Policy` during `save`

Comment: There is no need to pass `self` in `super` method.

Comment: @Charnel My bad, fixed.

Comment: @AKX, now it works, man, thanks a lot. But I have a little question: can I change `clean` method name or its required by django ?

Comment: [`clean()` is the Django model validation function.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work, because `start_date_time` is not a value, but a field that will keep a value.

As was mentioned in previous answer, you can override clean/save methods to set value for `end_date_time`. Another option is to use [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-save) or [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save) signals depending on when/how `start_date_time` is set.

Comment: Why `start_date_time` is not a value ? It keeps start date in it.

Comment: Because `start_date_time` is a class attribute (variable) assigned to a `DateField`. That's exactly what error is saying. DB keeps the value of this field and you can get it only by instantiating the class (formally by using one of the manager methods) indirectly.